# select key names base on subject values

Tags: json, select, key, jq

Hashicorp Vault provides me the following JSON:

```
{
  "somekey1/": {
    "accessor": "generic_123456,
    "config": {
      "default_lease_ttl": 0,
      "force_no_cache": false,
      "max_lease_ttl": 0
    },
    "description": "",
    "external_entropy_access": false,
    "local": false,
    "options": {},
    "seal_wrap": false,
    "type": "generic",
    "uuid": "1111111-2222-3333-4444-55555555555"
  },
  "somekey2/": {
    "accessor": "aws_123456",
    "config": {
      "default_lease_ttl": 3600,
      "force_no_cache": false,
      "max_lease_ttl": 86400
    },
    "description": "",
    "external_entropy_access": false,
    "local": false,
    "options": null,
    "seal_wrap": false,
    "type": "aws",
    "uuid": "1111111-2222-3333-4444-55555555555"
  },
  "somekey3/": {
    "accessor": "generic_1234567",
    "config": {
      "default_lease_ttl": 0,
      "force_no_cache": false,
      "max_lease_ttl": 0
    },
    "description": "",
    "external_entropy_access": false,
    "local": false,
    "options": {},
    "seal_wrap": false,
    "type": "generic",
    "uuid": "1111111-2222-3333-4444-55555555555"
  }
}
```

I want to determine which top level keys have a sub-object K/V .type="generic".
In this case, "somekey1/" and "somekey3/"

Or "somekey2/" with a sub-object K/V .type="aws".

Can this be accomplished with JQ?

Answer (score 2):

in this case, I use the following:

```
jq 'to_entries[] | select (.value.type == "generic") | .key' vault.json
```

which produces:

```
"somekey1/"
"somekey3/"
```

Which is exactly what I am looking for.